# Cannot fix Improper Restriction of XML External Entity Reference error

Tags: c#, xml, veracode

I have changed the code when trying to fix Veracode error for `Improper Restriction of XML External Entity Reference`, but it did not fix it.

Here is the code I have now:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc=new XmlDocument();
using (System.IO.MemoryStream xmlstream = new System.IO.MemoryStream
(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(dsEQ.GetXml().ToString())))
{
    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Prohibit;
    using (XmlReader xmlreader = XmlReader.Create(xmlstream, settings))
    {
        try
        {
            xmlDoc.Load(xmlreader);
        }
            catch(XmlException e)
        {
            Connection.LogError(e.ToString(), e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

However, Veracode still point out on this section of code with the same error message.

Is there anything else that I should do to fix it? We do not have any external references, everything is through intranet.

Comment: Try XMLTextReader instead of XMLReader.  Sometimes the Text Reader will accept errors that the XML Reader will reject.

Answer (score 1):

Set `XmlResolver` to null:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.XmlResolver = null;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: this does not work to resolve the scan.

Answer (score 1):

Set XmlResolver = null will fix the issue.

```
static void LoadXML()
{
  string xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?><!DOCTYPE doc 
    [<!ENTITY win SYSTEM \"file:///C:/Users/user/Documents/testdata2.txt\">]
    ><doc>&win;</doc>";

  XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
  xmlDoc.XmlResolver = null;   // Setting this to NULL disables DTDs - Its NOT null by default.
  xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);
  Console.WriteLine(xmlDoc.InnerText);
  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Please go through below link for more information.

[XML External Entity (XXE) Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XML_External_Entity_(XXE)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: Also confirmed by Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca3077-insecure-processing-in-api-design-xml-document-and-xml-text-reader?view=vs-2019

Comment: This does not resolve the veracode scan issue.

Answer (score 0):

The original answer works for xmlDoc.Load(xmlreader).

The second question is a different context and requires different technology.

```
    using (System.IO.StringReader rxml = new System.IO.StringReader(myxmltext))
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MenuConfigBase));

        using (XmlTextReader xr = new XmlTextReader(rxml))
        {
            xr.XmlResolver = null;

            var cfgBase = (MenuConfigBase)serializer.Deserialize(xr);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Again, also confirmed by Microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca3077-insecure-processing-in-api-design-xml-document-and-xml-text-reader?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 0):

None of the listed answers here allowed me to resolve the CWE-611 issue I was getting from Veracode.

Creating an [XmlSecureResolver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlsecureresolver?view=netframework-4.8#to-restrict-access-by-using-a-permission-set) with permissions set to none allowed me to resolve the issue.

```csharp
var xsr = new XmlSecureResolver(new XmlUrlResolver(), new PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.PermissionState.None));
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument { XmlResolver = xsr };
```